# Respond.js on Subdomain using Tumblr

Tags: cross-domain, tumblr, media-queries, responsive-design

[My website](http://www.stevechab.com) is responsive. The [blog section](http://blog.stevechab.com) uses a subdomain pointing to Tumblr, but the cross-domain version of Respond.js isn't working. I'm doing this:

```
<script src="http://www.stevechab.com/scripts/respond.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://www.stevechab.com/scripts/respond-proxy.html" id="respond-proxy" rel="respond-proxy">
<link href="http://www.stevechab.com/scripts/respond.proxy.gif" id="respond-redirect" rel="respond-redirect">
<script src="http://www.stevechab.com/scripts/respond.proxy.js"></script>
```

I assume the problem is that respond.proxy.gif and respond.proxy.js aren't on blog.stevechab.com ... but doesn't that defeat the purpose of having a cross-domain version of Respond.js? Is my assumption right, or am I missing something? Is there a work around for this?

Note: I tried http://www.tumblr.com/themes/upload_static_file ... no dice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To quote the `respond.js` readme:

> Respond.js works by requesting a pristine copy of your CSS via AJAX, so **if you host your stylesheets on a CDN (or a subdomain)**, you'll need to upload a proxy page to enable cross-domain communication.

– my emphasis. The cross-domain version is meant to enable you to process stylesheets loaded from another domain than the one `respond.js` is working on. In the case of Tumblr, however, you have *a third* domain added to the mix: `static.tumblr.com`, where your proxy script and gif have landed. That cannot, and will not, work.

Comment: I tried hosting the proxy script and gif on stevechab.com, and it didn't work. To be clear, you're saying there is no solution.

IE8 will see the mobile version of my site. Well, even if it's not pretty, at least it functions! Thanks!

Comment: @SteveChab: from the JS same domain origin policy point of view, `blog.stevechab.com` and `www.stevechab.com` are entirely different domains (and if you think this is silly, just ponder all the `foo.tumblr.com` sites – you wouldn’t want every script of every Tumblr to be able to mess with your site, I think :)), and so is their top-level domain (there is no inheritance, for the reasons just stated). There are ways around this, but not the way `respond.js` has ben designed to handle them.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks! IE8 and less users will just have to not know what they're missing.

Comment: @SteveChab - It's a good practice these days to not use respondjs anyways.  99.99% of IE8- users are using on desktop and don't need mobile styles.  Also, respondjs is known to to cause other fringe issues which makes it simply not worth the trouble.

Comment: @Ryan With a mobile first approach in CSS, I think respondjs is a logical choice.

Comment: @PimSchaaf - respond.js has nothing to do with mobile.  It has everything to do with making legacy browsers support media queries... which is a waste of time in my opinion and causes unnecessary work and headaches.

Answer (score 6):

@Steve Chab,

There are two reasons *respond.js* & *respond.proxy.js* were not working for you.

1. You had the *respond-proxy.html* file in the origin domain, whereas the file should have been served from your sub-domain (*blog.stevechab.com*) or any other external domain.
2. There seems to be a bug with *respond.js* / *respond.proxy.js* when linking to a css file with a relative url. To fix it, use an absolute url. Your main site uses a relative url for the css stylesheet, and your blog an absolute url.

   - *Note: Bug is caused by respond.proxy.js ajax/xml functions*

Please find below, the re-vised working markup to get *respond.js* & *respond.proxy.js* working on your website.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.stevechab.com/styles/styles.css">
<!--[if (lt IE 9) & (!IEMobile 7)]>
<link href="//blog.stevechab.com/scripts/respond-proxy.html" id="respond-proxy" rel="respond-proxy">
<link href="//www.stevechab.com/scripts/respond.proxy.gif" id="respond-redirect" rel="respond-redirect">
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<!-- Your content goes here. -->

<!--[if (lt IE 9) & (!IEMobile 7)]>
<script src="//www.stevechab.com/scripts/respond.min.js"></script>
<script src="//www.stevechab.com/scripts/respond.proxy.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</body>
</html>
```

- Respond.js on GitHub

  - http://github.com/scottjehl/Respond
- Respond.js Plugin for Wordpress

  - http://wordpress.org/plugins/respondjs/
- Respond.js used by Twitter Bootstrap

  - http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to "respond!" It's about time for me to redesign my site anyway ... so I'm not worried about fixing it. Hopefully, someone else will find this very useful. :)